# pandas to find earliest occurrence of statement and set to starter

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following df

```
  data = {'Name' : ['John','John','Lucy','Lucy','Lucy'],
            'Payroll' : [15,15,75,75,75],
            'Week' : [1,2,1,2,3]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Name    Payroll Week
0   John    15  1   
1   John    15  2   
2   Lucy    75  1   
3   Lucy    75  2   
4   Lucy    75  3
```

What I'm attempting to do is true apply a Boolean throughout a DataFrame very similar to this one with 2m+ rows and 20+ columns to find out when someone started

To find if someone is active or not I pass a condition to another df:

```
df2 = df.loc[df.Week == df.Week.max()]
```

This gives me the final week i then use an isin filter to find out if the person is active or has left

```
df['Status'] = np.where(df['Payroll'].isin(df2['Payroll']), 'Active','Leaver')
```

So using the above code I get the following which is great, which tells me that since John is not in the latest week he has left the company

```
Name    Payroll Week    Status
0   John    15  1   Leaver
1   John    15  2   Leaver
2   Lucy    75  1   Active
3   Lucy    75  2   Active
4   Lucy    75  3   Active
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to know when John started with us, I could try a mask for each week of the year and an isin to check for when they first appeared but I figured there must be a more pythonic way do this!

Desired output:

```
 Name   Payroll Week    Status
0   John    15  1   Starter
1   John    15  2   Leaver
2   Lucy    75  1   Starter
3   Lucy    75  2   Active
4   Lucy    75  3   Active
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit for Clarity :

```
data = {'Name' : ['John','John','John','John','Lucy','Lucy','Lucy','Lucy','Lucy'],
            'Payroll' : [15,15,15,15,75,75,75,75,75],
            'Week' : [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

desired output:

```
    Name    Payroll Week    Status
0   John    15      1   Starter
1   John    15      2   Active
2   John    15      3   Active
3   John    15      4   Leaver
4   Lucy    75      1   Starter
5   Lucy    75      2   Active
6   Lucy    75      3   Active
7   Lucy    75      4   Active
8   Lucy    75      5   Active
```

things to note:

Max week is 5 so anyone not in week 5 is a leaver

first week of person in df makes them a starter.

all weeks in between are set to Active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with new condition by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
a = df.loc[df.Week == df.Week.max(), 'Payroll']
m1 = ~df['Payroll'].isin(a)
m2 = ~df['Payroll'].duplicated()
m3 = ~df['Payroll'].duplicated(keep='last')

df['Status'] = np.select([m2, m1 & m3], ['Starter', 'Leaver'], 'Active')
print (df)
   Name  Payroll  Week   Status
0  John       15     1  Starter
1  John       15     2   Active
2  John       15     3   Active
3  John       15     4   Leaver
4  Lucy       75     1  Starter
5  Lucy       75     2   Active
6  Lucy       75     3   Active
7  Lucy       75     4   Active
8  Lucy       75     5   Active
```

Comment: Hey Jozi! this is close but Lucy would be set as Active as she's present in the df in the final week

Comment: @Datanovice - Can you check now?

Comment: @Datanovice - one thing, is necessary check Payroll column of `Name` ? Like `names = df.loc[df.Week == df.Week.max(), 'Name'].unique()

m1 = df['Name'].isin(names)` /

Comment: I don't think so as it's possible for people to have the same names, however the payroll column has unique values per person

Comment: @Datanovice - super, data are sorted in columns? So not necessary it?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, yes we should not use the name column but rather the payroll column which is sorted and cleaned in my df (also set to int64) i changed your 3rd code to the following `df['Status'] = np.where(df['Payroll'].duplicated(), df['Status'], 'Starter')`

Comment: this is very close Jozi, but it sets the status of a single person to leavers in every instance when I just want the last one. For example If I had John for 20 Weeks and my max weeks were 21 I would want status in week 1 = Starter, week 2-19 = Active and week 20 = Leaver as he's not present in 21. Sorry I should have been more clear in my question

Comment: @Datanovice - I think the best should be changed sample data, is it possible? Can you add some 2-3 new rows?

Comment: @Datanovice - Not sure if understand - `Max week is 5 so anyone not in week 5 is a leaver` - why is `Leaver` for week `4` ?

Comment: because that was the last week that john worked at the company, his absence from Week 5 means that he left in Week 4, does that make sense? the max week is the latest data that I get as a dump each week, its a list of all workers in the company and their absence from it means they left in the previous week

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way that I have come across is using `groupby` and finding minimal index for the name in the group:

```
for _, dfg in df.groupby(df['Name']):
    gidx = min(dfg.index)
    df.loc[df.index == gidx,'Status'] = 'Starter'

print(df)
```

And the `df` is then:

```
   Name  Payroll  Week   Status
0  John       15     1  Starter
1  John       15     2   Leaver
2  Lucy       75     1  Starter
3  Lucy       75     2   Active
4  Lucy       75     3   Active
```

Comment: awesome! let me test this, currently running on my lovely work laptop!

Comment: additionally, could this be used to find the last occurrence of an item in a df? I'd like to note someone as active until they are a leaver in their max week if its less than the dataframes max week

Comment: and final comment, anyway to do this without a for loop, I've always been reprimanded here for using them as pandas uses 2d vector arrays and doesn't work well with loops (especially as my df is 2million rows +)

Comment: You can change the `min` to `max` and you have the last entry. With this the changes are minimal. In terms of the for loop there is another approach I will post in a moment.

Comment: this sort of works for me, it works on my example DF it works on a subset of my DF but strangely when I run it on all my DF it exhibits strange behavior (maybe due to dtypes and size of DF)?

Comment: What is this strange behaviour?

Comment: it adds around 20 thousand rows with every value set to starter I think its my DF and not your code however