# Finding New/Existing Customers from a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a categorical column indicating whether the client account code has occurred for the first time i.e. "New" or it has occurred before i.e. "Existing".

Only the first occurrence needs to be considered as "New", the rest of the occurrences, irrespective of the gap in occurrences, should all be considered as "Existing".

I tried looping through the list of unique account codes within which I would filter the Dataframe for that particular account code and find the minimum date which would be stored in a separate table. Then looking-up to this table I would enter the New/Existing tag in the categorical column. Couldn't Execute it properly though. 
Is there a simple way to accomplish it?

I have attached the sample file below:

[Sample Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvuqjcu1ajt1c0u/SD_N-Ex_PBComm.xlsx?dl=0)

Also the Data has some non UTF-8 encoded characters which couldn't be handled by me.

Comment: Could we see what have you tried?

Comment: Please share a sample of the data instead

Comment: Please post a sample of the data in your question, not an image

Comment: Seems very similar to a question I've asked in the past, check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372676/pandas-to-find-earliest-occurrence-of-statement-and-set-to-starter/53373029?noredirect=1#comment93624748_53373029

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df.assign(Occurence=np.where(~df['Account Code'].duplicated(),'New','Existing'))
```

Output:

```
  Created Date   Account Code Occurence
0     7-Sep-13       CL000247       New
1     7-Sep-13       CL000012       New
2     7-Sep-13       CL000875       New
3     7-Sep-13       CL000084       New
4     7-Sep-13       CL000186       New
5     7-Sep-13       CL000167       New
6     7-Sep-13       CL000167  Existing
7     7-Sep-13       CL000215       New
8    12-Sep-13  Wan2013001419       New
9    12-Sep-13       CL000097       New
...
```

Comment: I like using assign sometimes because it returns a copy of the original dataframe instead of modifying there dataframe with something like `df['Occurance'] = ...`

Comment: It seems to work, Would like you to confirm whether the data needs to sorted according to the date before that operation?

Comment: @SaudMeethal Yes, if want to do it chronologically then yes, it needs to be sorted otherwise it simple use the first occurence ine the dataframe from top to bottom regardless of sort.